# While loops in Python 3

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm having some problems with some code for a menu system. What I have so far isn't completed but I'm having a problem with it. It works fine with the account.leeman' but I can never get 'administrator' to work, and it always rolls back to the beginning. I've looked at the code for a while now but I can't figure out why this is and why it doesn't ever continue. The 'add' part of the code can be ignored as it isn't a problem yet, although if you can see any way in improving it, please let me know

So this is what I have:

```
usernames=["m.leeman","administrator"]
passwords=["pA55w0rd","password"]
while True:
    count=0
    add_or_enter=input("Would you like to Enter a username or Add a new one?: ").lower()
    if add_or_enter=="enter":
        username=input("Please enter username: ")
        while (count+1)!=(len(usernames)):
            #problem somewhere here
            if username==usernames[count]:
                print("Username accepted")
                password=input("Please enter password: ")
                if password==passwords[count]:
                    print("Welcome "+str(username))
                    print("Continue here")
                else:
                    print("Incorrect password")
            else:
                count+=1
                if count==len(usernames):
                    print("User does not exit")
                else:
                    ()
                    #should run again after this
    elif add_or_enter=="add":
        new_user=input("Enter a new username: ")
        if (new_user=="add") or (new_user==usernames[count]):
            print("Username unavailiable")
        else:
            count=+1
            if count==len(usernames)-1:
                usernames.append(new_user)
                new_password=input("Enter a password for this user: ")
                passwords.append(new_password)
                print("User "+new_user+" successfully created")
```

Any replies will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Hypothetically, what happens if you do `while count != len(usernames):` instead?

Comment: Seems like there may be some hidden newlines in the user input from `raw_input` `username` and `"m.leeman\n"`, At the line after you have indicated `"#problem somewhere here"`, try `if username.strip()==usernames[count].strip():` to clean the strings and strip-off the newlines. Worked when I tried it.

Comment: A word of advice - use a dictionary with usernames as keys and passwords as values. It will be much easier to handle and won't require all this loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never get to administrator because you are double incrementing count. you have count being incremented in the condition and then in the else statement when it doesn't = m.leeman so take out the count+=1 after the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at this line of code:

```
while (count+1)!=(len(usernames)):
```

On the first loop, count is 0 so 0+1 != 2 and the loop executes. Their inputted name "administrator" won't match "m.leeman" so count is increased by one and the loop will execute again.

This time, count = 1. So count + 1 = 2, which happens to be the length of usernames. The loop doesn't execute and the admin account is not found.

The solution? Remove the + 1

```
while count != len(usernames):
```

Hope this helps